Earnings dates of certain stock tickers in Python
I want to get a list of dates where earning reports happened for S&P500 stock tickers. I'm using yfinance and Streamlit modules in Python language and getting this error message:
"Error fetching earnings data for WMB: Have not implemented fetching 'earnings' from Yahoo API".
Current code:
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests
from io import StringIO

# Function to fetch earnings report dates for a given ticker
def get_earnings_dates(ticker):
    try:
        stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        earnings = stock.earnings
        return earnings
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching earnings data for {ticker}: {e}")
        return None

# Function to generate earnings report dates for S&P 500 tickers in the past year
def generate_earnings_reports():
    try:
        # Fetch S&P 500 tickers
        url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/s-and-p-500-companies/master/data/constituents.csv"
        data = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8')
        sp500_tickers = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))['Symbol'].tolist()
        
        print(f"Found {len(sp500_tickers)} S&P 500 tickers.")
        
        earnings_data = {}
        for ticker in sp500_tickers:
            print(f"Fetching earnings data for {ticker}...")
            earnings = get_earnings_dates(ticker)
            if earnings is not None and not earnings.empty:
                earnings_data[ticker] = earnings['Earnings Date'].tolist()
        return earnings_data
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating earnings report dates: {e}")
        return None

# Streamlit app
def main():
    st.title('S&P 500 Earnings Report Dates')

    earnings_data = generate_earnings_reports()

    if earnings_data:
        st.write("Earnings Report Dates for S&P 500 Stocks in the Past Year:")
        for ticker, dates in earnings_data.items():
            st.write(f"Ticker: {ticker}")
            st.write("Earnings Report Dates:")
            for date in dates:
                st.write(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            st.write("---")
    else:
        st.write("Failed to fetch earnings report dates for S&P 500 tickers in the past year.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


This looks to me like incomplete implementation (or a bug) on the part of the yfinance library. I would open a issue with them.
